# Calling function from string within jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I am trying to assign a string as the name of a function within the jQuery code but there is something wrong with what I am doing. In the code below, I am passing `name="hello"` as the function name and `msg="hello world!"` as the argument. I am trying to call the `hello(msg)` function. Any help will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jhveokn/

HTML

```
`<input type="button" value="Click me!">`
```

CSS

```
input{
    width: 100px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input').click(function(){
    var name = 'hello';
    var msg = 'hello world!';
    window[name](msg);
});

function hello(msg){
    alert(msg);
}
});
```

Comment: Maybe use eval() instead?

Comment: First of all: this is not a jQuery- but a JS-question. Ad your problem: `eval` is pure evil but it will be your friend here.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid eval() but I will check to see if I can use it in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have defined the method `hello` with the closure of the dom ready handler, so it won't be a property of the window object, only global variables/function are accesible as property of window object.

So either assign it as a property of the window object

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').click(function() {
    var name = 'hello';
    var msg = 'hello world!';
    window[name](msg);
  });

  window.hello = function hello(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click me!">
```

---

Or define it outside of the closure

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    var name = 'hello';
    var msg = 'hello world!';
    window[name](msg);
  });
});

function hello(msg) {
  alert(msg);
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click me!">
```

---

But a more appropriate approach could to use a different object than the window object like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').click(function() {
    var name = 'hello';
    var msg = 'hello world!';
    fns[name](msg);
  });

  var fns = {};
  fns.hello = function hello(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click me!">
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8adjtn3w/2/

Comment: Thanks. I understand why I can't call the window object anymore. I just have to assign it to a different object.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('input').click(function(){
    var name = 'hello';
    var msg = 'hello world!';
    //window[name](msg);
    eval(
        'function '+name+'(msg){ alert(msg); }');
    );

});
```

});

Answer (score -1):

```
window.hello = function(msg) {
  alert(msg);
};
```